# Using HTTPS, I am getting the parameters null in index.jsp page

Tags: jsp, https

When I enter this url with https at the address bar in the browser.
https was not taking i.e. why i am specifying separately.

`ipaddress:portno/PaymentGatewayFormNew/index.jsp?DebitAmount=23&MerchantId=pyro123&MerchantPassword=1234&SessionId=635237&remarks=VasTransaction&RequestDevice=app&callbackUrl=ipaddress:portno/pg`

this turns out to be only 
`ipaddress:portno/PaymentGatewayFormNew/index.jsp`

and rest of the parameters are not coming.

Also, I checked in `index.jsp` using `request.getParameter("DebitAmount")`, I got all the parameters null.

**Before https, it was okay.**

i.e. When I was using this url with http only.
It was working.
But with https, it is not working.

Please help. I m not able to know/guess why it is happening.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. After putting the `https` URL in the address bar and hitting enter, does the URL in the address bar change?

Comment: Pass the values as `POST` request instead of `GET` that is not safe specially in case of `https`.

Comment: Why would an index page be taking in a password?  Rebuild the whole app from scratch and this time don't try to build it all as one jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

When you use https for your website, first you have to enable it in the server and deploy your code. For that you need to have some certificates too.

Comment: If that was it he'd be getting like a page not found error, not seeing the page but with the parameters null.